# Proving something is not differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am looking for confirmation so that I can be sure I understand what is being asked here. I need to show that the following function $f(x,y)$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$ but that $g(x,y)=yf(x,y)$ is:

$$
f(x,y) = \left \{
\begin{array}{ll}
{\frac {x^2 y} {x^2 + y^2} } & \mbox{ if $x,y\neq 0$ } \\
0 & \mbox{if $x=y=0$}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

If the differential exists at $(x,y)$, then there is a linear mapping $f'(x,y):\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$f(x+tu,y+tv) - f(x,y) = f'(x,y)(tu,tv) + r(tu,tv)$$

where $r(tu,tv)/t \rightarrow 0$ as $t \rightarrow 0$. At $(x,y)=(0,0)$, this implies that

$$
\frac{u^2 v}{u^2 + v^2} = f(tu,tv) = f'(0,0)(tu,tv) + r(tu,tv)
$$

since $f$ is nonlinear, $f'(0,0)$ cannot exist.

However, following the same line of reasoning for $g(x,y)$ gives:

$$
\frac{u^2 v^2 t}{u^2 + v^2} = g'(0,0)(tu,tv) + r(tu,tv)
$$

Thus, as $t \rightarrow 0$, we have that $g'(0,0)(tu,tv) \rightarrow 0$, which means that $g'(0,0)$ is simply the linear operator defined by $g'(0,0)(x,y)=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f = 0$ on both coordinate axis, the partial derivative of $f$ (if they exist) must be $0$. Hence, if $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ it would have to be the case that

$$
f(x,y) - f(0,0) = \frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2} = r(x,y),
$$

where $r(x,y)/\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \to 0$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$. Analyzing this limit, by passing to polar coordinates, we get
$$
\frac{r(x,y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \frac{x^2y}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} =
\frac{r^3 \cos^2\theta \sin\theta}{r^3} = \cos^2\theta\sin\theta
$$
and it's clear that this does *not* tend to $0$ (for most values of $\theta$) as $r \to 0$.

I'll leave the corresponding analysis of $yf(x,y)$ to you.

Comment: Thanks. I do appreciate it. I do not, however, understand where your first equation is coming from. As $(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)$, the difference on the left should approach a linear mapping. I don't see this in what you have written.

Comment: The linear mapping is $0$.

Comment: I see now. Thanks.

Comment: May I know how to see the partial derivative of f (if they exist) must be $0$?